# Is there a way to watch inputs when we are using v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am having array of objects and looping the same using v-for and I need to watch the inputs based on the value I am selecting.

```
<tr v-for="(key, index) in NewArr" v-bind:key=value>
<td>
    <multiselect
        v-model="key.NameSelected"
        :loading="Loading"
        :options="NameList"
        :closeOnSelect="true"
        placeholder="Select One - type to search..."
        selectLabel='select'
        deselectLabel='remove'
    ></multiselect>
</td>
<td class="modify-td-padding__multi">
    <div class="modify-input-fixed-width">
        <input type="text" name="ValueSelected"
        v-model="key.ValueSelected"
        class="input-increase-height">
    </div>
</td>
```

Here I need to keep watch for key.NameSelected. I dont know how to do as I am new to VueJS. I am stuck at this point. Someone please help.

I tried normal watch method like,

```
NameSelected: function () {}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can only *watch* `data` properties / `props` / `computed` of a Vue component.

> So, you cannot *watch* `key.NameSelected` which is local to the template's
>   looping element. Instead you can *watch* the `NewArr` which I assume is
>   a data property.

```
watch: {
 NewArr: {
  handler (newValue, oldValue) {
   // Issue: but, this will be invoked if anything inside NewArr will change
  }
 }
}
```

> Instead, if you want to look for a change of *particular select*, I
>   will *recommend* you to use an **event**.

```
<multiselect
    v-model="key.NameSelected"
    :loading="Loading"
    :options="NameList"
    :closeOnSelect="true"
    placeholder="Select One - type to search..."
    selectLabel='select'
    deselectLabel='remove'
    @input="handleInput" <-- Trigger handleInput for specific multiselect
></multiselect>

export default {
 methods: {
  handleInput (value, id) {
   // do something with value & id
  }
 }
}
```

*PS: You can use other **events** as well in place of `@input` as per use case. [doc](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-events)*

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, i need to make change like this, if(key.nameselected = "number") i need to display value as "number " in "key.valueSelected". if(key.nameselected = "text"), then i need to display value as "text" in "key.valueSelected". Now whats happening means, whatever i am selecting, it is applicable to all fields. not particular input

Comment: The event is coupled to a specific element, If you do not want that, the above watch is coupled with an entire array & obviously, in the handlers you can do whatever you want, ie. to update for a select or for all.

Comment: So, in either of the handlers, you can check this condition: `if(key.nameselected = "number")` as you will the have the `key` value, & you can update your `NewArr` on a particular `index` as well as again you will have the index in the handler. So, this. `NewArr[index].nameselected = "whatever you want in the handler"` will do the job to update the DOM as per updated data.

Comment: sorry, its not working. mine is different scenario. pls provide your mailid, will share more details. need some help.

Answer (score 0):

You could call a method, when the user inputs something. Like:

In your Template add:

```
<multiselect @input="userInput(key.NameSelected)"></multiselect>
```

in your script:

```
methods:{
 userInput(input){
  console.log(input);
 }
}
```

You can see the [docs](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-events)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Actually, i need to make change like this, if(key.nameselected = "number") i need to display value as "number " in "key.valueSelected". if(key.nameselected = "text"), then i need to display value as "text" in "key.valueSelected". Now whats happening means, whatever i am selecting, it is applicable to all fields. not particular input